# Creating C++ Redis Module - "does not export RedisModule_OnLoad() symbol"

Tags: c++, redis, g++, shared-libraries, symbols

I am having some trouble loading my Redis module. I am just copying the example from https://redis.io/topics/modules-intro, but I stripped it down.

```
#include "redismodule.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int RedisModule_OnLoad(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, RedisModuleString **argv, int argc) {
    if (RedisModule_Init(ctx,"avromodule",1,REDISMODULE_APIVER_1)
        == REDISMODULE_ERR) return REDISMODULE_ERR;


    return REDISMODULE_OK;
}
```

This is saved in avromodule.cpp. I compile it using the following:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o avromodule.so avromodule.cpp
```

Then I go over to the Redis CLI and try to load the module.

```
10.XXX.XXX.XXX:7004> module load /path/to/module/avromodule.so
(error) ERR Error loading the extension. Please check the server logs.
```

The server logs give me the following error:

```
159392:M 17 May 10:21:19.773 # Module /path/to/module/avromodule.so does not export RedisModule_OnLoad() symbol. Module not loaded.
```

The above error makes no sense to me, because I get the following output using the 'nm' command:

```
$ nm -CD avromodule.so | grep " T "
0000000000003622 T RedisModule_OnLoad(RedisModuleCtx*, RedisModuleString**, int)
000000000000366c T _fini
0000000000002878 T _init
```

Does anyone have a clue what could be going wrong here? I know that I am using C++ as opposed to the recommended C, but this should still work AFAIK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because `RedisModule_OnLoad` is getting [name mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) by your C++ compiler.

`RedisModule_OnLoad` is getting re-named to to `__Z18RedisModule_OnLoadP14RedisModuleCtxPP17RedisModuleStringi` by GCC, so Redis is unable to find the exported symbol it is looking for.

```
$ nm avromodule.so | grep OnLoad                   
0000000000000970 T __Z18RedisModule_OnLoadP14RedisModuleCtxPP17RedisModuleStringi
```

You can use the `extern "C"` directive to ensure your exported symbols remain un-mangled.

```
#include "redismodule.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int RedisModule_OnLoad(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, RedisModuleString **argv, int argc) {
    if (RedisModule_Init(ctx,"avromodule",1,REDISMODULE_APIVER_1)
        == REDISMODULE_ERR) return REDISMODULE_ERR;


    return REDISMODULE_OK;
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Which results in an un-mangled symbol getting exported

```
nm avromodule.so | grep OnLoad                   
0000000000000970 T _RedisModule_OnLoad
```